# How to get shell color output with Flask and ansi2html

Tags: python, shell, flask

I am trying to display the output of a ansible-playbook using flask and ansi2html, its outputting the results fine except its not got any color just white on black.

Fairly new to the world of flask and this is good but it just needs that extra bit, happy for any pointers at all, including something alternative to ansi2html.

Here is the code block for the particular route.

```py
@app.route("/resetprovideo/")
def resetprovideo():
    conv = Ansi2HTMLConverter(inline=True)
    file = request.args.get('file')
    folder = request.args.get('folder')
    files = []
    for item in os.listdir(folder):
        if item.endswith(".tune"):
            files.append(item)
    try:
        if file not in files:
            raise ValueError("Error Filename Incorrect!")
    except ValueError as err:
        return "An Error has occured ... {}".format(err)
    else:
        def runit():
            script = './reset_provideo.sh '
            cmd = script + file
            session = subprocess.Popen([cmd], 
                                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                        shell=True, 
                                        universal_newlines = True)
            for line in iter(session.stdout.readline, ''):
                yield conv.convert(line.rstrip()
            session.communicate()
            exit_code = session.wait()
            if int(exit_code) == 0:
                exit_code = 'Successfully Completed!'
            else:
                exit_code = 'Somthing Went Wrong -- rc = ' + str(exit_code)
            yield exit_code
        return Response(runit(), mimetype='text/html')
```

As stated, this works, it just displays white text on a black background.

Thanks in advance

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So It turns out it was passing the color all along, which was NO COLOR from ansible.

Setting the config item

```
force_color = 1
```

Bingo bongo, we got color.